# Least recently used algorithm

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, virtual-memory

[I am studying for exam i came across this question.and i cant understand how they got the answer can any one explain it? write the assumptions made and if it is asked for 10 marks how to write it]

Consider the two-dimensional array A:

```
int A[100] [100];
```

where A[0][0] is at location 200, in a paged memory system with pages of size 200. A small process that manipulates the matrix resides in page 0 (locations 0 to 199); thus, every instruction fetch will be from page 0. For three page frames, how many page faults are generated by the following array-initialization loops, using LRU replacement, and assuming frame 1 has the process in it and the other two frames are initially empty?

```
for(int i=0;i<100;j++)
    for(int j=0;j<100;i++)
        A[i][j]=A[i+200][j+200];
```

Comment: Write down a trace of the page frames requested by the references to A[i][j] and allocate each page to the three-entry page-table.

Comment: Does the operating system only load one page on a page fault?
is there a limit to the working set size?

Comment: there is no limit @user3344003